# Elasticsearch Java - use Search Template to query

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have below code working fine in my java service.

```
 Query searchQuery = new StringQuery(
    "{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"match\":{\"id\":\"" + id + "\"}}]}}");
 SearchHits<Instance> instanceSearchHits = elasticsearchOperations.search(searchQuery, Instance.class, IndexCoordinates.of("test"));
  log.info("hits :: " + instanceSearchHits.getSearchHits().size());
```

Now, I want to save this query as a template in elastic and just pass params and search template from java service to elastic to execute the query.

Search Template added in Elastic

```
PUT _scripts/search-template-1
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "id": "{{id}}"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "params": {
      "id": "id to search"
    }
  }
}
```

Call this template

```
GET test/_search/template
{
  "id": "search-template-1",
  "params": {
    "id": "f52c2c62-e921-4410-847f-25ea0f3eeb40"
  }
}
```

But unfortunately not able to find API reference for the same to call this search template from JAVA (spring-data-elasticsearch)

Comment: You can easily do it with the [High Level REST Client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.rest)

Comment: I can see these three different queries option https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.operations.queries but not able to find anywhere to use search template

Comment: You're not looking at performing queries, but saving a search template. This is what you're looking for: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-search-template.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [val](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604579/val) this can be used to call the search template query from java

```
SearchTemplateRequest request = new SearchTemplateRequest();
request.setRequest(new SearchRequest("posts"));

request.setScriptType(ScriptType.STORED);
request.setScript("title_search");

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("field", "title");
params.put("value", "elasticsearch");
params.put("size", 5);
request.setScriptParams(params);

 SearchTemplateResponse response = client.searchTemplate(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        SearchResponse searchResponse = response.getResponse();
        SearchHits searchHits = searchResponse.getHits();
        log.info("hits :: " + searchHits.getMaxScore());
        searchHits.forEach(searchHit -> {
            log.info("this is the response, " + searchHit.getSourceAsString());
        });
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not yet possible. There is [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/1891) for this in Spring Data Elasticsearch.